# Удаление результата из полученного селекта в Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица где есть поле типа character varying[]. В этом поле сохраняется номера телефонов в таком виде [+012345678901","+123456789012","2347587E+11"]. Как мне найти в этой таблице "неправильные" номера телефонов такого вида - 2347587E+11 и удалить? И чтоб после удаления в массиве было типа так:

1. Массив до удаления [+012345678901","+123456789012","2347587E+11"]
2. Массив после удаления [+012345678901","+123456789012"]

P.S. Использую postgresql

Comment: разобрать массив (array_unnest) => отфильтровать элементы (например regexp`ом)  => собрать массив (array_agg)

Comment: Сделал так, SELECT unnest(ARRAY(SELECT phones FROM subject_phone WHERE "phones"::text like '%E%')). Собрал в одну колонку. Дальше что делать? Подскажите пожалуйста готовым скриптом.

Comment: вы ошиблись с порядком выполнения запросов, сначала исполняется самый вложенный (запрос который глубже всех по скобочкам поиск идет с права на лево :)

Comment: Это как? Можно по подробнее. )

Comment: Готовым скриптом - не поделюсь, не в моих правилах это :)

Comment: ```Это как? Можно по подробнее. )``` => explain {ваш sql запрос} => вывод: план выполнения вашего запроса.

Comment: SELECT unnest(ARRAY(SELECT phones FROM subject_phone WHERE "phones"::text like '%E%')) - вот это правильно ли я делаю? Что неправильно в этом скрипте?

Comment: Примерно всё, запрос в обратную сторону, если упростить донельзя то вот так оно должно быть записано(то что я вам в первом комментарии подсказал), но в таком виде как я привожу - это работать не будет.... ```select array_agg(t.phone) from (select array_unnest(phone) phone from XXX) as t where {ваш фильтр}```, но сюда надо добавить еще немного условий чтобы использовать этот запрос для обновления данных

Comment: Я могу обновить с помощью UPDATE или надо array_replace ?

Comment: сможете если допишите верно запрос, именно через update и нужно обновлять :)

Comment: Тогда я сейчас попробую дописать. Потом Вы можете проверить? :)

Comment: Если буду в сети - смогу, будут вопросы - можете уточнять, но тогда лучше перейти в чат.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. :)

Comment: UPDATE subject_phone SET phones = array_replace(
(SELECT ARRAY(
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT unnest(ARRAY(SELECT phones FROM subject_phone WHERE "phones"::text like '%E%'))) as t WHERE t.unnest like '%E%'
)), 'E', '0') WHERE "phones"::text like '%E%';

Comment: Попробовал такой вариант, но что-то не получилось. Результат запроса. Убрал все  "правильные" номера, оставил все "неправильные". :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141165/discussion-between-cool-dude-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов, через вставку и разрешение конфликта:

```
insert into phones 
    with t as (select 
        ph.id,
        unnest(ph.phones) as phone  
    FROM 
        phones ph )
    select 
        id,
        array_agg(phone) as phones 
    from 
        t 
    where phone like '%2%' // << место с фильтрацией "неверных" номеров
    group by 
        id 
on conflict(id) do update set phones = excluded.phones
```

Еще вариант через апдейт с условием:

```
update phones p set phones = t.phones from 
(with t as (select 
        ph.id,
        unnest(ph.phones) as phone  
    FROM 
        phones ph )
    select 
        id,
        array_agg(phone) as phones 
    from 
        t 
    where phone like '%2%' // << место с фильтрацией "неверных" номеров
    group by 
        id 
) as t(id,phones) where p.id = t.id
```

Еще вариант с подзапросом (без конструкции with, именно на него я вам намекал в комментариях):

```
update phones p set phones = t.phones from 
(
    select 
        id,
        array_agg(phone) as phones 
    from 
        (select 
            ph.id,
            unnest(ph.phones) as phone  
        FROM 
            public.phones ph
        ) as t(id, phone)
    where phone like '%2%' // << место с фильтрацией "неверных" номеров
    group by 
        id 
) as t(id,phones) where p.id = t.id
```

Comment: Спасибо за варианты решений. Попробовал все эти три. Не помогло. Значение не обновились. Хотя скрипты выполняются без ошибок.

Comment: фильтр верный?))

Comment: Да. вот такой поставил - where phone::text like '%E%'

Comment: Давайте в чат под вопросом :)

Comment: Спасибо, Владимир. Проблема решилась.